# Download go packages via http proxy

Tags: git, go, http-proxy

I'm trying to download go packages via my http_proxy.
For now, i've edited my .gitconfig and it looks like:

```
[http]
        proxyAuthMethod = basic
        sslVerify = false
        proxy = http://mydomain\\username:passwd@myproxy:8080
[credential "http://myproxy:8080"]
        provider = generic
[https]
        proxyAuthMethod = basic
        sslVerify = false
        proxy = http://mydomain\\username:passwd@myproxy:8080
```

Git clone via proxy works fine (so it means my proxy works correctly):

```
$ git clone https://github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-go.git -v
Cloning into 'clickhouse-go'...
warning: ----------------- SECURITY WARNING ----------------
warning: | TLS certificate verification has been disabled! |
warning: ---------------------------------------------------
warning: HTTPS connections may not be secure. See https://aka.ms/gcm/tlsverify for more information.
warning: auto-detection of host provider took too long (>2000ms)
warning: see https://aka.ms/gcm/autodetect for more information.
POST git-upload-pack (185 bytes)
POST git-upload-pack (gzip 4262 to 2162 bytes)
remote: Enumerating objects: 7076, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (368/368), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (116/116), done.
remote: Total 7076 (delta 258), reused 359 (delta 251), pack-reused 6708
Receiving objects: 100% (7076/7076), 2.52 MiB | 5.12 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (4915/4915), done.
```

But when i'm trying to add go modules with `go mod tidy` i get this error:

```
PS C:\Users\user\go\src> go mod tidy
go: finding module for package github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-go/v2
main imports
        github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-go/v2: module github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-go/v2: Get "https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/%21click%21house/clickhouse-go/v2/@v/list": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup http: no such host
```

What should i configure so `go mod tidy` would work?

Answer (score 1):

Can you confirm that your proxy is set to what you expect?

Try typing `go env` in console and check the value of `GOPROXY`.